# HTML5 File Input customization on label giveing Keyboard accessibility issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, uiaccessibility

If we hide the HTML File Input element and customize its lable then when we test for keyboard accessibility check there is no focus border is coming
Although the file system window is opeining when we press keyboard's tab and then enter but no indication on screen when the window is opening.

Is there any way to highlight or add focus to the input without showing it in the screen as it is hidden and the css is given to the input label. The functionality works fine but it fails when it comes to accessibility issue.

I have tried using position absolute like that but the its not working as the input is hidden and has no width and hight

Html

```
<form class="form" id="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="uploadButton" class="file__label">
        upload File
    </label>
    <input type="file" accept="text/csv" id="uploadButton" name="fileInput" class="file__input">
</form>
```

css

```
.form {
  width: 180px;
}
.form .file__label {
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 180px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #5e10b1;
  border: 1px solid #5e10b1;
  margin: 0;
}

.form .file__label:hover {
  background-color: #f6f3f9;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #5e10b1;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.form:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.form:focus .file__label {
  outline: 2px solid #ffbf47;
}
.form .file__input {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If I understood well you are trying to hide inpu[type=file] and make another well CSS-ed button, that will click your inpu[type=file], if yes then my answer should work, you just needed visibility:hidden

Comment: I edited answer now when you press tab it's highlighted

Answer (score 0):

I commented outline none so when you'll press tab it will show border

```js
 function fclick() {document.getElementById("pic").click()}
```

```css
        .filebtn {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
/*    outline: none;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 9px 24px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(105, 132, 163);

        }
        .filebtn:hover, .update:hover {
    background-color:rgb(142 167 195)
    }
    .hdn {visibility: hidden}
```

```html
<button  class="center filebtn" onclick="fclick()">Upload an image</button>
<input type="file" name="picture" id="pic" class="hdn">
```